# Display only stories in serenity report

Tags: selenium, automation, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I am using Selenium, JBehave and Serenity and I was wondering if there is a way to only display the stories which have failed/passed in the serenity report not the scenarios.
For example if I have one story file with 5 scenarios and one scenario fails I want to see the whole story failed in the report and not the status of the scenarios.
Would that be possible and how?

Thanks!